# I'm trying to code something that when someone gets or loses a role it sends a message to a set channel

Tags: discord.py, pycord

I'm trying to have the bot send a message every time someone receives and loses the Dark Role and Light Role in a set channel but for some reason, the dark clan leave and join message stops working once I add the light clan one. I'm somewhat new to discord.py but still, know quite a few things.

This is my code:

````
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name='Dark Clan')
    channel = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name='-dark-clan')
    if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
        await channel.send(f"Welcome to the Dark Clan {before.mention}!")
    if role in before.roles and role not in after.roles:
        await channel.send(f"{before.mention} left the clan.")

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    roled = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name='Light Clan')
    channeld = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name='⚪-light-clan')
    if roled not in before.roles and roled in after.roles:
        await channeld.send(f"Welcome to the Light Clan {before.mention}!")
    if roled in before.roles and roled not in after.roles:
        await channeld.send(f"{before.mention} left the clan.")```
````

Comment: Just use `not in` in the condition.

Comment: Hey zqki, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've noticed that the past three questions you have asked are very similar, they should be moved into one question as not to spam the site.

Comment: But then how do I move them into one question even though the other questions are already answered?

Comment: You need a moderator's assistance, which I can provide.  In the future, please avoid asking repeated questions so that it won't be necessary.

Comment: I've updated my answer to what you want, even though I commented on your 3rd question on the same topic on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by combining both the dark and light clan script.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name='Dark Clan')
    channel = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name='-dark-clan')
    if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
        await channel.send(f"Welcome to the Dark Clan {before.mention}!")
    if role in before.roles and role not in after.roles:
        await channel.send(f"{before.mention} left the clan.")
    roled = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name='Light Clan')
    channeld = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name='⚪-light-clan')
    if roled not in before.roles and roled in after.roles:
        await channeld.send(f"Welcome to the Light Clan {before.mention}!")
    if roled in before.roles and roled not in after.roles:
        await channeld.send(f"{before.mention} left the clan.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `on_member_update()` event for that.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name='Dark Clan')
    channel = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name='-dark-clan')
    if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
        await channel.send(f"Welcome to the Dark Clan {before.mention}")
    if role in before.roles and role not in after.roles:
        await channel.send(f"{before.mention} left the Dark Clan")
```

Comment: I have another question (I edited the question)

Comment: You are overriding the event because you are defining it twice, check the channel names  as well, discord.utils.get cannot find it, that is why you get that error. Remove one of the functions and use lists for different roles and channels. I am not here to code your bot for you.